# Facebook post embed 100% width on desktop

Tags: css, facebook, embed

This seems like a common question, but I can't find a straight answer.

I'm trying to get a Facebook post embed to be 100% width of it's parent div. All the solutions seem to be about Facebook comments, not the post embed feature.

I've tried adding `data-width="100%"` and `width: 100%` to the iframe, but nothing is working so far.

Comment: could you post an example, a snippet would be nice

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
iframe {
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your that the parent container of the iframe is set to a specific width: 100% if it's relative to some other parent's width.. else make it 100vw for a full width of the page (viewport), or give it's parent some specific width in px, or whatever you are using. . only then the iframe will be able to take 100% of the width of its parent.

```css
.parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 900px;
  background: black;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</div>
```